# Can't see the HDD unallocated space from windows on gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I currently have three booted up operating systems on my Desktop:

- Kali Linux
- Ubuntu
- Windows 10

The three of them are booted up from my SSD. both Ubuntu and Kali /home partitions are as shown in the picture below partitioned on my HDD

[image: Windows Disk management]

Now as you can see in the picture, I created an unallocated space of 200gb to add to my Ubuntu /home partition. However the problem is I cannot see the unallocated space in gparted as free space. As a matter of fact I cannot see the unallocated space at all. The highlighted partition of 34.81 GB in the picture is my Ubuntu /home folder.

[image: Gparted partitions HDD]

How can I resize ubuntu /home folder if I cannot see the unallocated space in there ? and why can I not see it ?

Comment: Apparently it's because your disk was converted to Dynamic disk and the unallocated space is in the LDM data partition ( [3425.9 + 200] / 1024 = 3.54). Not sure if/how you can shrink it to get the space out though. And I suggest you do some research to make sure it is safe to shrink it with gparted, if it provides you an option.

Comment: @TomYan you are saying because HDD is converted into Dynamic space ? if so I need to convert it into what ?

Comment: would it be to basic disk ?

Comment: Well yeah I'm referring to `Dynamic` instead of `Basic` shown for the disk in `Disk Management`. I am not sure if Windows allows you to convert it back for a "system drive", nor am I sure if it's necessary (maybe you can just shrink the `LDM data partition` (`sdb3`) in some way so that the unallocated space will "get out" naturally).

Comment: I cannot shrink the LDM data from gparted that is for sure

Comment: Have you tried right click on the unallocated space and see if `Disk Management` gives you an option about moving it out? Also try look into `diskpart`. Sorry I have no experience in dynamic disk at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are third-party tools that claim to be able to convert from LDM/dynamic disk format to a conventional partition setup. [MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/) and [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/personal.html) both claim to have this capability; however, I've never used either tool, and so I can't vouch for either of them. I ***strongly*** recommend that you back up all your personal data, and ideally *everything,* from any disk before you attempt this sort of operation.

It looks like the disk isn't a boot disk, so another option is to back it up, repartition it, and restore it. If you do this, I recommend doing the partitioning from Linux, since then you'll be less likely to accidentally create another LDM setup. (LDM is a Windows-specific type of disk format.)

Comment: can you use the tool on a disk that is already divided into multiple partitions like Disk 1?